# CSS: select all starting from n-th element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select all child elements starting from n-th element? For example I have a div with 7 spans and I need to select all spans starting with 3-rd element, so 4,5,6,7 should be selected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`div>span:nth-child(2)~span` should do the trick. The `~` General Sibling Combinator selects all following elements. The spec is at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

Comment: Not sure a specced part of the W3 selectors module counts as a trick! It’s not something I use on every site but every now and again it’s irreplaceable.

Comment: It’s a trick in the sense that it uses an unnecessarily complicated selector (cf. to @RobertKoritnik’s answer).

Comment: I agree with @JukkaK.Korpela. It is a bit superfluous as the same can be done in a more simple way. But it's a nice trick in a sense of clever use of general sibling combinator.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela just re-read this and understood why you referred to it as a trick ‍♂️ Yeah, Robert’s way is neater.

Answer (score 14):

### CSS2.1 selector

```
span + span + span + span {
    /* matching a span that has at least 3 siblings before it */
}
```

### CSS3 selector

```
span:nth-child(n+4) {
    /* matching from 4th span on */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
div:nth-child(n+3) {
    // your style here   
}
```

However, this does not specifically select elements 3-7. Instead, it excludes the first two elements. So it would also select elements 8,9, ...